# Postgres: Add full-text search on existing varchar column?

Tags: postgresql

I have an existing Postgres 9.3 database with a table with a varchar column.

```
        Table "public.frontend_chemical"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+-----------
 bnf_code  | character varying(9)   | not null
 chem_name | character varying(200) | not null
```

I would like to run full-text search on the `chem_name` column.

I have been reading [this article](http://dlo.me/archives/2014/09/01/postgresql-fts/), which suggests the steps are as follows:

1. Add a new `tsvector` column: `ALTER TABLE frontend_chemical ADD COLUMN fts_document tsvector;`
2. Create a function to map the `chem_name` column to the document, and a trigger to keep it updated.
3. Create a GIN index on the column: `CREATE INDEX chem_fts_index ON frontend_chemical USING gin(fts_document)`;

Then I should be able to run full-text search queries like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM frontend_chemical WHERE fts_document @@ 'statin';`.

Firstly, is that general process correct?

Secondly, how do I map all the existing entries in the `chem_name` column to the `fts_document` column? The example in the article seems to only update the `document` column when the `chem_name` column is updated, whereas I have a large existing database.

Answer (score 21):

This process is correct but maybe overkill in your case.

As a single column needs to be full-text searched, you may do away with the dedicated `tsvector` column, and create only the GIN index as:

```
CREATE INDEX chem_fts_index ON frontend_chemical
    USING gin(to_tsvector('simple',chem_name));
```

Instead of `simple`, you may specify `english` or another available [configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS) if  linguistic rules are needed.

Then you'll benefit from the index when searching with:

```
select columns from frontend_chemical where
   to_tsvector('simple', chem_name) @@ to_tsquery('simple','expression to search');
```

The key point being that the `tsvector` expression is exactly the same as in the GIN index.

This has the advantages of not requiring a trigger, of saving the space of the dedicated column whose values are already in the index anyway, and of not requiring to initialize that column (your 2nd question).

---

Should you want that column anyway, it should be initially populated with an update query of this form:

```
UPDATE frontend_chemical SET fts_document = to_tsvector('simple', chem_name);
```

(again, assuming `simple` as the text search config)

---

EDIT following comments:

`to_tsquery()` with only one argument uses the default text configuration (otherwise the configuration name should be passed as the first argument).
If this default does not match the one used in `to_tsvector`, that's a problem. The default can be changed in several ways:

- for the duration of the session (not persistent)

  ```
      SET default_text_search_config to 'simple';
  ```
- for the database (persistent)

  ```
      ALTER DATABASE nameofdb SET default_text_search_config to 'simple';
  ```
- otherwise, always use the two-arguments form for `to_tsquery` with the explicit text configuration name as the first argument (I've changed the example above to use that form).

To search for a prefix as you seem to want with *`Ro`*, you may use this condition:

```
to_tsvector('simple', chem_name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'Ro:*')
```

See [Controlling Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html) in the manual for more.

Comment: The only problem is that queries don't seem to do anything: `select * from frontend_chemical where to_tsvector('simple', chem_name) @@ to_tsquery('Ro')` produces no results, where `select * from frontend_chemical where chem_name like 'Ro%'` produces lots of results. Have I misunderstood how to make the query?

Comment: A `\d` shows that the index is definitely present on the table: `"chem_fts_index" gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, chem_name::text))`, and I've run an `ANALYZE` as well.